# Implementation of array with negative indices

Tags: c#, arrays

I am making a game with a world that extends infinitely in every direction. This means that you can be at position `X:50`, `Y:50` or `X:-50`, `Y:-50`. But... I can't really do that with a normal C# List...

All the ideas I've come up with seem to be too complicated/inefficient to work...

Comment: Normally it's implemented with the modulus operator

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: nevermind my comment above, I was thinking of something else. See my answer below instead.

Comment: computers can't store infinite arrays, this is a wrong code writing pattern.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to implement infinite grid is using a sparse matrix with a dictionary with an x,y pair as the key and the data you want to store as the values. This is fast, easy to implement, and memory friendly if your grid is sparse.

Another way is a linked grid (similar to linked list, but with pointers to 4 directions), or a tile-based approach to reduce the overhead of linked grid (a tile is a linked grid of NxN arrays). Implementation of tiles is quite complicated, but is a good tradeoff between memory and performance for very dense grids.

But my personal favorite approach is to use the even-odd transformation. So odd indices are positive, while even numbers are negative. To transform from virtual index to the physical index, you use the formula `p = abs(v * 2) - (v > 0 ? 1 : 0)` and to convert physical to virtual index you do  `v = (p % 2 == 1 ? +1 : -1) * ((2*p + 3) / 4)`. This relation arises because there is one to one and onto relation (bijection) between natural numbers and integers `(0 <-> 0), (1 <-> 1), (2 <-> -1), (3 <-> 2), (4 <-> -2), (5 <-> 3), (6 <-> -3), ...`. This approach is fast, simple and elegant, but not very great memory wise when you have very sparse grid with items extremely far from the center line.

Comment: I think the even-odd approach will work just fine for what I'm doing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a TON (yes, a TON of bits...) of cells, you can use dictionaries. Combine that with a `System.Drawing.Point` as the key, and you get a good thing going on:

```
Dictionary<Point,YourGridObject> myMap = new Dictionary<Point,YourGridObject>();
```

Edit: In addition to the dictionary, each cell can have a reference to it's adjacent cells, this way you can use the dictionary to directly go "somewhere", but then navigate with the adjacent. I used that way to implement an A* pathfinding algorithm in an hex grid.

Edit 2: 
For example, if you then want to access a specific coordinate, you can simply

```
var myTile = myMap[new Point(25, -25)];
```

Then, you want to get the `East` tile, you can

```
var eastTile = myTile.East;
```

Your grid object could also implement an offset method so you could get the 'West 2, North 5' tile by

```
var otherTile = myTile.Offset(-2, 5);
```

Comment: So lets say I wanted to find what was at position `25`,`-25`... would I use the `.Where(...)` function?

Comment: Instead of adding reference to adjacent cells, it may be easier to store reference to the Point object instead, you can find the neighbors by adding/subtracting to/from the Point's coordinate. Depending on the structure of your program, these denormalization might be very helpful or complicate unnecessarily.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins I added some elements in my answer, but it's just suggestions. I don't know exactly what you want to do with your tile, but the best way to implement it really depends on how you're going to use it.

Comment: @LieRyan Referencing the adjacent cells instead of storing the coordinate might be faster in some cases, rather than querying the dictionary. It really depends on how many tiles he has. the down side is really if serialize/deserialize I think. In my scenario, you'd have to recreate all the associations after a deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

How about using two List underneath for expansions in two different directions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this is more complicated than you want to deal with, but have you considered using polar coordinates instead of cartesian?  There are no negative numbers in that coordinate system.  I realize that the coversion is difficult at first, but once you wrap your head around it, it becomes second nature.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dictionary, which has all the capability of an array except with negative indexes obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Computers cannot store infinite arrays.
There must be a boundary to your array, remind that somewhere in code you declared a specific size during initialization of your array.
Perhaps you resize it somewhere, but that still leaves an number range from 0..to.. max.

So what you should do, write a function that allows for relatively positioning in such a map. So you store your current map[x,y] as a position.
And your able to go up, by having a function that add/substracts from your current position relativly. 
This keeps your code easier to understand too.

If your not dealing with game maps but number ranges, lets say vectors
you could create a list of n points, or a 2d dictionary.

I'm posting it here, cause your problem might lead people to writing wrong code.

Also adding for other people in situations where there is a border around a map (typical in games scenario, and image manipulation.
where your data goes from  [-1..width+1] just dimension it as [0,width+2]
then loop trough it starting 'for (int x = 1; x < Width+1; x++)'