# Array with negative indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which I'm using to store map data for a game I'm working on.

```
MyMapType[,,] map;
```

The reason I'm using a fixed array instead of a Collection is because fixed arrays work very much faster.

Now my problem is, I'd like to have support for negative z levels in the game. So I'd like to be able to access a negative index.

If this is not possible, I thought of a pair of other solutions.

I was thinking as a possible solution to have ground-level as some arbitrary number (say 10), and anything less than 10 could be considered negative. But wouldn't this make the array 10 times larger for nothing if its not in use?

Another solution I considered was to 'roll my own' where you have a Dictionary of 2D arrays, with the Z level held in the List as the index. But this is a lot more work and I'm not sure if its slow or not.

So to summarise - any way of creating an array which supports a negative index? And if there's not - is there a clean way of 'emulating' such behaviour without sacrificing too much CPU time or RAM - noting that these are game maps which could end up large AND need to be accessed constantly.

Comment: Adding 10 extra elements to an array does not make it larger by an order of magnitude (unless the array only had ~1 element to start).

Comment: @MattBall - Its a multidimensional array, wouldn't a 10x10x1 be 1/10th the size of a 10x10x10 ?

Comment: @SLaks - I had it as a dictionary originally, but that works a few hundred times slower I've found. And I can't sacrifice that.

Comment: If you're going for speed, multidimensional arrays are a bad idea. They are far slower than single-dimensional arrays. If the map data you are constructing is mostly empty space or has a lot of redundancy then an immutable quadtree might be a better data structure than an array; access is slower, but you can represent an arbitrarily large area in a relatively small amount of memory. And they support negative indices easily.]

Comment: All that said, this question isn't a very good fit for the site. Try to ask a *specific question* about *actual code*.

Comment: @EricLippert - Are you sure? I always assumed that multidimensional arrays (not the jagged kind) were internally single dimensional ones with some simple math to get to the right record.

Comment: @EricLippert - #2 - It is a specfic question - How can I make negative indices without making it slow or massive?

Comment: @Haedrian: They are single dimensional arrays with simple math to get to the right record. But the math is done by a helper method and this causes overhead. If you profile it you'll find that multidimensional array access is pretty slow in .NET compared to other variable access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementation of array with negative indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837139/implementation-of-array-with-negative-indices)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

replace your arrays with a class:

```
class MyArray {
    private MyMapType[] myArray = new myMapType[size]
    MyMapType this[index] {
       get{return myArray[index + offset];}
    }

}
```

you can set the size and the offset in the constructor or even change it at will.

Building on this example here is another version:

```
class MyArray {
    private MyMapType[] positives = new myMapType[size]
    private MyMapType[] negatives = new myMapType[size-1]
    MyMapType this[index] {
       get{return index >= 0 ? positives[index] : negateves[1-index];}
    }

}
```

It does not change the fact that you need to set the size for both of them. Honestly I like the first one better

Comment: this solution will make him define the offset.

Comment: The problem is that I need a multidimensional array. So I'll need to rewrite a bunch of code to get the xth,yth,zth value. Hmm.

Comment: @aguyngueran yes, but he wants to do it anyway, and this is unavoidable anyway. defining the offset is no different then defining the size, and you cannot get away without this if you want arrays

Comment: @Haedrian taking into account Eric Lippert comment consider a single dimensional array of classes

Comment: Hmm, I do like your second one, and it'll work for a multidimensional array without adding too much overhead (I'll consider a quadtree like Eric Lippert suggested if I find its too slow, but for my purposes I think it'll be quick enough)

Answer (score 7):

If you want "negative" indexes C# 8 now supports it.

```
var words = new string[]
{
                // index from start    index from end
    "The",      // 0                   ^9
    "quick",    // 1                   ^8
    "brown",    // 2                   ^7
    "fox",      // 3                   ^6
    "jumps",    // 4                   ^5
    "over",     // 5                   ^4
    "the",      // 6                   ^3
    "lazy",     // 7                   ^2
    "dog"       // 8                   ^1
};              // 9 (or words.Length) ^0
```

So the to call the negative one would be like this

```
words[^1]
```

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8)

So in your case the middle element could be the zero Z

Comment: going to just point out that calling `words[^1]` would be equivalent to calling `words[8]` which to be blunt is not equal to calling `words[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

Use the Dictionary class, since you can assign whatever values you want for either the key or value. While I'm not sure how this would work for the 3-dimensional array that you showed above, I can show how this would work if this were a 1-dimensional array, and you can infer how to best make use of it:

```
MyMapType[] map;

//map is filled with w/e data

Dictionary<int, MyMapType> x = new Dictionary<int, MyMapType>();

x[-1] = //(map data for whatever value is for the negative value);
x[0] = map[0]
//(etc...)
```

Comment: I had the very same idea. But I also just needed a **1-dim** array that goes in both directions. Should be possible with a 3D array as well: `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, MyMapType>>>`

Comment: I found this to be a great solution! I had a 2D array (grid) that needed to support negative indexes. Switching from `Cell[,]` to `Dictionary<(int, int), Cell>` gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to store a list of MyMapTime[,] in two lists:

- one for z values of greater than or equal to 0
- and second of negative z-values.

The index of the tables would be the value of z.
Having this would let you access quickly the xy-values for specific z-level.
Of course the question is: what are your z-values? Are there sparse or dense.
Even for sparse values you would end up with an array holding null values for [,].

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to note here that dictionaries allow for negative indexes
and a 2D dictionairy can solve problems like these too, just think about the datastructure and if you can live with a dictionary

note that dictionaries and lists are used in different scenario's.
and their speed depends on what functions are used on them