# VB6 C# migration xh(-1)

Tags: c#, arrays, vb6-migration

I would like to know the equivalent C# expression for this `xh(-1)` which is in VB6.

Where `xh()` is declared as `Public xh() As Object`

It seems like a negative index of on array but it sounds nonsense in C#.

Can some one please tell me what does really mean?

Code:

```vb
Public xh() As Object   
.. 
If typr(0) = "a" Or typr(0) = "r" Then 
    xh(0) = 0
    xh(-1) = 0 
Else 
    xh(0) = -xh(1)
    xh(-1) = -xh(2) 
End If 

If typr(na) = "a" Or typr(na) = "r" Then 
    xh(nht + 1) = act
    xh(nht + 2) = act 
Else 
    xh(nht + 1) = 2 * act - xh(nht)
    xh(nht + 2) = 2 * act - xh(nht - 1) 
End If

... 
If typr(0) = "a" Then 
    xh(0) = 0
    xh(-1) = 0
    xh(1) = acr(1)
    xh(2) = acr(1) 
Else 
    xh(0) = -xh(1)
    xh(-1) = -xh(2) 
End If
```

Comment: Can you show some more context and real code?

Comment: Well, in VB6 you could use negative array indexes. If you are translating it to C#, you would have to change that to 0-based arrays. Anyway,as @PatrickHofman says, we'd probably need to see more code to get the context

Comment: This shouldn't work in VB6 either if that is really the declaration -- the default base is 0 unless overridden by an `Option Base` statement (or explicit bounds are included in the declaration). Is there such a statement?

Comment: Depending on how want to solve this, it's either a Possible duplicate of [.Net arrays with lower bound > 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/56446/11683) or Possible duplicate of [Array with negative indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15730346/11683).

Comment: ok thaks @Pikoh

Comment: BTW,as @JeroenMostert has told,i think that code shouldn't work unless the object is declared as `Public xh(-1 to 2) As Object` or something similar